# does not change css file in rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Rails application.

Problem: file app/stylesheets/application.css doesn't changes in output html.
application.css

```
body {
  font-family: micfont;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  min-width: 1200px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  background-image: url(header.jpg);
}
```

app/views/layouts/index.html.haml

```
%html
  %head
    %title SkyDance
      = stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all"
      = javascript_include_tag "application"
      = stylesheet_link_tag    "bootstrap_and_overrides", :media => "all"
      = csrf_meta_tags
  %body
    .navbar-wrapper.navbar-margin-top
      .container
        .navbar.navbar-opacity-white
          .navbar-inner
            %a.btn.btn-navbar{ "data-target" => ".nav-collapse", "data-toggle" => "collapse" }
          .nav-collapse.collapse
            %ul.nav
              %li
                %a{ :href => about_welcome_index_path }= t('.about_us')
              %li
                %a{ :href => schedule_path }= t('.schedule_and_prices')
              %li
                %a{ :href => genres_path }= t('.dances')
              %li
                %a{ :href => teachers_path }= t('.teachers')
              %li
                %a{ :href => contacts_welcome_index_path }= t('.contacts')
  .row-fluid  
    .container.content
      = yield
   = render 'layouts/footer'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved.

I have changed the file in production environment. Every time when you need to change any source file in assets directory, you must to precompile your assets.

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```